# Strange animation behavior on mouseover/out events

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have two events:

```
$('li').on({
    'mouseover':fadeImgOut,
    'mouseout' :fadeImgIn
});
```

and functions...

```
function fadeImgOut() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({opacity:'.5'}, 1000);
}
function fadeImgIn() {
    $(this).find('img').animate({opacity:'1'}, 1000);
}
```

When I hover on it, the image `fadeout, fadein and fadeout` and when I'm moving the mouse out, the image `fadein, fadeout and fadein` again.

I can't explain this behavior: why the image not fading-in on `mouseover` and fading-out on `mouseout`?

Comment: Change it to mouseleave/mouseenter and use stop()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$('li').on({
    'mouseenter':fadeImgOut,
    'mouseleave' :fadeImgIn
});
```

Or better

```
$('li').hover(fadeImgOut, fadeImgIn)
```

Comment: Worked! why mouseenter/mouseleave are working and mouseover/mouseout are not?

Comment: `mouseout` of li will get fired when you move the mouse pointer to a child element, but `mouseleave` will be fired only when you move of element to an outside element

Comment: @Lior If you read the API docs for mouseover, youll see "This event type can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune times. See the discussion for .mouseenter() for a useful alternative."

Comment: @lan That was VERY useful. I will definitely look into it. Thx for putting your time!